# spring batch cron expression meaning

Tags: spring, cron, cronexpression

What does following cron expression mean?

```
<property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 1/6 * * ?" />
```

Following is how 0/30 works, but I don't know how 1/6 will work.

```
"0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30 and 10 o'clock every day.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by trial and error method.

```
"0 0 1/6 * * ?"
```

means run the batch job at 1AM, 7AM, 1PM, and 7PM everyday.